# How do you set the name attribute of a TextBox control in a .Net 3.5 project?

Tags: asp.net, controls, attributes

Self explanatory really

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Textbox server control doesn't have a name property. A HTML Input control has a name property. Use the "ID" property.