# Getting input tool "name" by using C# asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

As title, how should I do to get the input tool its "Name" from HTML by using asp.net C#.

The HTML code as follow:

```
<input type="number" Name="patientId" class="form-control" id="input1" runat="server">
```

What I tried in asp.net C# was `this.input1.Name.ToString();`, but the name I got was same with id "input1", not the one "patientId".

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: I think this explains your question.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2684266/5068518

Comment: Also, you can spot difference between `id` & `name` in HTML context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html. You can capture control ID as target, but you need to use postback submit for identifying name attribute.

Comment: It's worth asking "why" or "what for", before you get into possible "unnecessary" things.

Comment: The reason why I wanna get both value from name and id is because I wanna use a for loop to read all the input tool in a webpage by using "input" + i and then also get the meaning of this input tool by getting from its name.